# Prove $\binom{0}{8}+\binom{1}{8}+\cdots+\binom{n}{8}=\binom{n+1}{9}$ for all $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: induction, binomial-coefficients

This is textbook problem. Trying to prove by induction first for $n=1$ I get:

$$\frac{0!}{8!(0-8)!}+\frac{1!}{8!(1-8)!}=\frac{2!}{9!(2-9)!}$$

In all three fractions I have negative factorials, and factorials are as far as I know defined for positive integers only. What would $(-8)!$ be? $(-8)(-7)\cdots(-1)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Factorial_formula)
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$
only works if $n\geq k\geq 0$.

If $n < k$, then 
$\binom{n}{k} = 0.$
You can take this as a definition, or this can be deduced from the definition
$$\binom{n}{k} = (\# \text{ of $k$-element subsets of an $n$-element set}).$$
If $n<k$, it is not possible for an $n$-element set of to have a $k$-element subset.

As a hint to your textbook problem, have you seen how the binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$ fit together in [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle)?